How can I make a function that throws a popup error
like the title says,
this is what I currently have, it works fine in the console, I can see the log and my message in it but only in the System Console which I have to toggle manually, I want the user to see the error as a pop up like in most blender errors
my operator:
class BlenderUnityHelperErrorReporter(Operator):    
bl_idname = "blenderunityhelper.errorreporter"
bl_label = "Blender Unity / Error Reporter"

txt_error = ""

def execute(self, context):
    self.report({'ERROR'}, BlenderUnityHelperErrorReporter.txt_error)
    return {'FINISHED'}

function which I want the error to pop up, but it only displays in the console?
def LogError(text):
    BlenderUnityHelperErrorReporter.txt_error = text
    bpy.ops.blenderunityhelper.errorreporter('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

Blender Version: 4.2.3

I have a custom exporter addon that uses something like this to display error/success messages to the user. I actually got the idea from renderjhs FBXBundle addon, but the whole addon essentially rewritten from the ground up to suit my needs. But still; credit where credit is due.
This is the main execute method of my Operator. I cut alot of the bulk of the code out just to illustrate the point.
def execute(self, context):
    # the part where it does the actual exporting
    exporter = Exporter(context, self)
    exporter.export()

    def draw(self, context):
        filenames = []
        unwritten_file_msg = ""

        # Bunch of code to get a list of the files that were successfully 
        # exported and files that couldn't be exported due to the file being 
        # read-only. All successes are appended to the filenames list, 
        # unwritten files are added to the unwritten_file_msg variable

        ... 

        # then add a number of label to the menu with the  
        # message I want to show the user.
        if filenames:
            self.layout.label(text="Exported {}".format(", ".join(filenames)))
        if unwritten_file_msg:
            self.layout.label(text=unwritten_file_msg)

    # Then this part calls a popup_menu using that draw function 
    # 
    context.window_manager.popup_menu(
        draw, title="Exported {}x files".format(len(exporter.bundles)), icon="INFO"
    )
    return {"FINISHED"}


many thanks!, I understand the concept now, I'm gonna make use of the context.window_manager.popup_menu to make a custom error popup dialog with some icon and stuff, again thanks, P.S: didin't know you could have draw methods inside the execute method xd

@Shaanig these are called local scope functions, they only exist in the context of the function they are defined in. Main advantage is it doesn't pollute any wider scope namespace.
